# How to pass JSON data over URL in Java?

Tags: java

I want to send some JSON data over URL, please any one tell me how to do that.
My URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/rest/users/query?Key=100&Token=200&Data={"Name":"Ramesh"}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Search for "Java curl" or "Java JSON" to  make a start on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache.http.client library to send your data:

```
RequestBuilder rb = RequestBuilder.post();
        rb.setUri(url);
        rb.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        rb.addHeader("Accept","*/*");
        rb.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString))
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(rb.build());
```

Where jsonString your data in json